# New Line not being written on file (Qt)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, qt

i am keeping a log of activities in my software using qtextedit. later when i want to save it as a text using toPlainText(), the resulting text file is a single line without any line breaks. 
I start logging by plainText() and add subsequent additions using append().

```
void rocketscience::saveLog(){
QFile logFile;
QTextStream logOut;
QString logfName;

QSettings prevSet("us","fr");

    if (defaultDir.exists(prevSet.value("settings/logPath").toString()))
        logfName= QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"Save File",fName,"Text (*.txt");


    if (logfName!=NULL){

    logFile.setFileName(logfName);
    logFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    logOut.setDevice(&logFile);
    logOut<<ui.statusReport->toPlainText();
    logFile.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the QTextStream class reference (that line is a bit hidden):

> Note: On Windows, all '\n' characters are written as '\r\n' if QTextStream's device or string is opened using the QIODevice::Text flag.

where '\n' is the UNIX line ending and '\r\n' is the Windows line ending (CR/LF).

Remove the QTextStream initialisation at the start of your method and change the if statement to this:

```
if (!logfName.isEmpty())
{
    logFile.setFileName(logfName);
    logFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    QTextStream logOut(&logFile, QIODevice::Text);
    logOut<<ui.statusReport->toPlainText();
    logFile.close(); 
}
```

Also note how I changed the if condition. logfName is by default set to "", I'm not sure if comparing to NULL will work. You're better off using the QString::isEmpty() function

Comment: Since it is a local variable, it won't be NULL. NULL is a valid value for pointer types.

Comment: There might be a QString overload for that, but I've been too lazy to check for that so I said I wasn't sure ;)

Comment: There is no `QTextStream` constructor that takes a `QFile` pointer and IO device open mode. There is one that takes in a `FILE*`, different from `QFile`. Instead, the open mode should be supplied to the file opening - `logFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);`

Answer (score 2):

Probably the file is written using UNIX line endings? You should open the file in text, to get the local (Windows) line-endings:

```
  logFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Text);
```

Comment: Short, succinct answer that works like a charm. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. However, the solution given by @Tim Meyer, did not work for me. In the line:

```
QTextStream logOut(&logFile, QIODevice::Text);
```

An error is shown. So, I did the following and worked for QT5.8:

```
/**
* Method to save a text file.
* @param asFileName: Complete file path, including name and extension.
* @param asText: Text to be written in the file
* @return true if the save was successful, false otherwise.
*/
bool MainWindow::saveFile(QString asFileName, QString asText)
{
    QFile file(asFileName);

    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)){
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"Error","File could not be opened");
        return false;
    }

    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << asText;
    file.close();

    return true;
}
```